Anyone seeing problems with 24.04 graphics/video freezing in virtualbox?
I am having a problem with the video freezing in a Ubuntu 24.04 guest.
At some point during use after powering on, maybe today, maybe tomorrow, maybe after a few minutes (haven't nailed that down); moving the mouse across the virtual will cause the VM's video to freeze.
The mouse still works, you can still do stuff, but you have to wait until the mouse has been still for a few seconds for it to release the hold on the screen and you see the results of your actions. This does not freeze the PC's screen, just the VM's.
As long as the position of the mouse is not changing, the VM plays fine. So scrolling, R/L-click, FWD/BACK buttons will not cause the problem.
I have toggled every remotely related feature I could think of in virtualbox. I have even wiped the VM.
Common search words like "freeze" and "video" have made it hard to yield effective search results. Admittedly, I haven't parsed through the logs. But scanning through them, nothing jumps out... and the fact that I have no idea when the problem starts, makes it hard to focus on a place in the logs.
host - MATE 24.04
guest - MATE 24.04
nouveau graphics - running through a Nvidia card
guestadditions - 7 (uninstalled after suspicion... dont know if that reverted it back to 6... but it still happens, so that seems irrelevant. Other VMs have 7 installed)
virtualbox - 7.0.16
guests - 18.04, 22.04, Rocky 9, Centos 8, 20.04... do not display the issue
resolution - 1920x1080 on all involved, except maybe the CentOS VMs as they dont have desktops.
mouse - logitech MX vertical, wired connection
Have there been any rumblings of similar issues with 24.04+virtualbox? Any known remedies or things to focus on? Is this a case of 24.04 being "too new"?

I've seen the same on older Ubuntu releases. And then I chose Lubuntu for a virtual machine.

Came here hoping for an answer. Yes, I am getting regular freeze-ups in my Ubuntu 24.04 guest.  It just becomes unresponsive and I have to hard power off the guest.  None of my other VMs (older Ubuntu versions) do the same.
